# Using dynamic typing to call other methods than object's

Tags: c++

Say I have a model which consists of a bunch of base and derived type object pointers stored in a vector.

```
Class Potato
{...};

Class SmallPotato : public Potato
{...};

Class Model
{
public:
    std::vector<Potato*> allPotatoes;
    ...
};
```

Now when implementing the corresponding view, I need a display() method for every kind of objects, but I don't want to mess up the model with view's stuff, so I put these methods inside a View class:

```
Class View
{
public:
    ...
private:
    display(Potato &potato) {...}

    display(SmallPotato &potato) {...}

};
```

Now when displaying the model from inside the View class, I need to display the model's objects using the right display methods, but I obviously can't use dynamic binding here. I also don't want to do magic like trying to dynamic_cast each object to *every* single derived type either. Is there any reasonable solution which lets me do something like the following?

```
void View::displayModel(Model &model)
{
    for (Potato *potato : model.allPotatoes)
    {
        //has to call the right thing for Potato, SmallPotato, etc.
        display(*potato);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), here we come.

Comment: You kinda have to use dynamic binding for `Potato`, even if it's the small utility `virtual void accept_view(View& v) { v.display(*this); } `